# how to solve $ 3^x \equiv 1 \pmod 7$?

Tags: number-theory

Pretty much the title. I know the answer is $x=6k$ where both $x$ and $k$ are positive integer numbers , but how do I know that there are no more solutions?

Comment: By Fermat's Theorem $3^{6}\equiv 1\pmod 7$. If $x$ be the order of $3$ modulo $6$ then $3^{x}\equiv 1\pmod 7$ and $x\mid 6$. So $x=1,2,3,6$. None of which satisfies the congruence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to consider only $6$ cases:

- $x\equiv\color\red0\pmod6\implies3^x\equiv3^{6k+\color\red0}\equiv(3^6)^k\cdot3^\color\red0\equiv729^k\cdot  1\equiv1^k\cdot  1\equiv1\pmod7$
- $x\equiv\color\red1\pmod6\implies3^x\equiv3^{6k+\color\red1}\equiv(3^6)^k\cdot3^\color\red1\equiv729^k\cdot  3\equiv1^k\cdot  3\equiv3\pmod7$
- $x\equiv\color\red2\pmod6\implies3^x\equiv3^{6k+\color\red2}\equiv(3^6)^k\cdot3^\color\red2\equiv729^k\cdot  9\equiv1^k\cdot  9\equiv2\pmod7$
- $x\equiv\color\red3\pmod6\implies3^x\equiv3^{6k+\color\red3}\equiv(3^6)^k\cdot3^\color\red3\equiv729^k\cdot 27\equiv1^k\cdot 27\equiv6\pmod7$
- $x\equiv\color\red4\pmod6\implies3^x\equiv3^{6k+\color\red4}\equiv(3^6)^k\cdot3^\color\red4\equiv729^k\cdot 81\equiv1^k\cdot 81\equiv4\pmod7$
- $x\equiv\color\red5\pmod6\implies3^x\equiv3^{6k+\color\red5}\equiv(3^6)^k\cdot3^\color\red5\equiv729^k\cdot243\equiv1^k\cdot243\equiv5\pmod7$

---

Therefore:

$$3^x\equiv1\pmod7 \iff x\equiv0\pmod6$$

Answer (score 2):

There is no other solution:

One way is to use Fermat's little theorem.

By Fermat's little theorem, the order of $3$ must be a divisor of $\phi[7]$ (i.e. $6$). So the order of $3$ must be in $\{1,2,3,6\}$. Check these number seperately and find that $6$ satisfies the condition.

The other way is to find the minimal cycle:

$3^1 \equiv 3 \pmod 7$,$3^2 \equiv 2 \pmod 7$,

$3^3 \equiv 6 \pmod 7$,$3^4 \equiv 4 \pmod 7$,

$3^5 \equiv 5 \pmod 7$,$3^6 \equiv 1 \pmod 7$.

After $3^7 \equiv 3 \pmod 7$, the cycle happens.

So there is no case that $3^n \equiv 1 \pmod 7$ where $n  \equiv w \pmod 6$, where $w \neq 0$.

Comment: Fermat's little theorem says that $3^{6k} \equiv 1$, but it does not rule out $3^2 \equiv 1$ or $3^3 \equiv 1$. That must be done separately. Also, after checking those, one might be worried that there are other exponents larger than $6$ but not divisible by $6$ that solves the equation. This must all be addressed.

Comment: @Arthur So do you know a good way to check other exponents larger than 6 but not divisible by 6?

Comment: @stenvikteam Yes. Note that if $x$ is large but not divisible by $6$, then $x$ is of the form $6r+s$ for some $r,s$ with $s$ positive and less than $6$. This gives $3^x=3^{6r+s}=3^{6r}\cdot3^s\equiv 1\cdot 3^s$, which cannot be congruent to $1$ since we ruled out the small exponents. And Zack: what about the order of $2$ modulo $7$?

Comment: @arthur I have updated it. is there any error?

Comment: No errors any more, no. Maybe a short sentence or two about why there is a cycle, but otherwise a much better answer than it was.